# MySQL - how to find contents of page_number

Tags: mysql

I recently had a MySQL Database crash with the following error:

`[ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of page [page id: space=36, page number=1365437]`

Is there anyway to find out the contents of page number 1365437 were.

I can get the table affected from `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE SPACE = 36;`

but can't see any easy way to find the contents of the `page`.

n.b. this was a MySQL 5.7 database.

Comment: page number * page_size (16k default) and that's the offset in the file.